# How do I save images from markdown into an s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, form-data

Users on our site can write posts using markdown, and upload an image using an input file. I've already set it up so that any images that get uploaded using the input element are uploaded to an s3 bucket, but how do I add the markdown images as well? Right now I'm sending the data to my nodejs backend from the react frontend using formData(). I've got it to the point where I can send a single image file from either the input option or the markdown, but it won't let me upload any more than this.

Does anyone know how I can send more than one image file to the backend using formData(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`FileList` is not supported in `FormData`, so you need to append each file.

```
for(let image of images) {
  formData.append("images", image)
}
```

Comment: I couldn't send more than one image because I was using the multer function 'upload.single()'. Wow, I'm a dumbass  Great use of several hours trying to fix this